# Is there any disadvantage to retaining state this way with a fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I've recently developed a new pattern for storing fragment state through a retained fragment. Instead of saving things in `onSaveInstanceState` as such:

```
public class MyActivityOrFragment {
  public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle bundle) {
    bundle.putInt("example", 123);
  }

  // plus restore in onCreate
}
```

I keep a state fragment like this:

```
public class MyActivityOrFragment {
  public static class State extends Fragment {
    int example = 123;
    public void onCreate(...) {
          ...
          setRetainInstance(true);
    }
  }
  State state;

  public void onCreate(Bundle ssi) {
    if (ssi == null) {
      state = new State();
      getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(state, "state").commit();
    } else {
      state = (State) getFragmentManager().findByTag("state");
    }
  }
}
```

With a lot of state to keep this reduces so much boilerplate since I can just keep it in the state fragment and know it'll be retained automatically. However, is there any disadvantage to using the retained fragment instead of saving to the bundle as usually recommended? Is this too good to be true?

Comment: Check this out: https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick

Answer (score -1):

Per Android documentation.

With setRetainInstance() you can retain your fragment while the application is running.

> Control whether a fragment instance is retained across Activity
>   re-creation (such as from a configuration change).

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html

But, it will not retain it if your Activity is destroyed. That's what onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState are for.

> As your activity begins to stop, the system calls
>   onSaveInstanceState() so your activity can save state information with
>   a collection of key-value pairs.
>
> When your activity is recreated after it was previously destroyed, you
>   can recover your saved state from the Bundle that the system passes
>   your activity. Both the onCreate() and onRestoreInstanceState()
>   callback methods receive the same Bundle that contains the instance
>   state information.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

Answer (score -1):

It is bad way use fragment then onSaveInstanceState(), becouse approach with fragment consume more memory.